# Грамотная адаптивная верстка?

Tags: javascript, адаптивная-верстка

Всем доброго времени суток.
При адаптивной вёрстке вы заморачиваетесь такими вещами как: 
-Page Speed(использование кэша браузера и т.п.)
-Оптимизация файлов(подключение/отключение требующихся скриптов, картинок и т.п. при разных расширениях, то есть не просто все(что нужно и не нужно) подгружать при всех расширениях)

Я о подобных вещах читал в книге Итана маркотта: отзывчивый веб-дизайн.
Или всем этим занимается кто-то другой(seo и т.п специалисты)?

Answer (score 3):

Заморачиваюсь следующим :)

- Оптимизация обращений к DOM
- Сжатие JS и CSS файлов
- Объединение js, css, графических файлов в спрайты
- Оптимизация циклов, рекурсий и других затратных процедур в JS
- Редко использую динамическую подгрузку картинок
- Для адаптивных иконок использую векторные форматы
- AJAX-подход уменьшает трафик

Идти по пути оптимизации при крупном проекте сложно, особенно по жесткой оптимизации связанной с подзагрузкой изображений под разные dpi. Обходимся разумными методами. А для своих проектов конечно можно попробовать, но это больше спортивный подход.

Но к рекомендациям Google Page Speed можно прислушиваться, там толковые советы, тем более, кажется, это влияет на позиции в поиске.